# Manipulating / Organizing ManyToManyField values in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I see a lot of people reccomending `ManyToManyFields` for the Following / Follower model in Django now that we can add that to a user model easily.

How would you, for example group the users you were following into separate user-created categories (like Circles on G+) using a `ManyToManyField` instead of a separate app where you'd easily be able to manipulate based on the relationship's id?

Answer (score 0):

You can get information from living models like this https://github.com/mkai/django-followers/blob/master/followers/utils.py
Just see how they made function `get_people_following_user` and compare to [UserLink model](https://github.com/mkai/django-followers/blob/master/followers/models.py#L6)